# Android WebView not loading URL

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-webview

I want to load the [URL](http://www.teluguoneradio.com/rssHostDescr.php?hostId=147) in `WebView`

I have used the following Code:

```
webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview1);
webView.setWebViewClient(new HostsWebClient());
webView.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(false);
webView.getSettings().setPluginsEnabled(true);
webView.getSettings().setSupportMultipleWindows(false);
webView.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
webView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(false);
webView.setHorizontalScrollBarEnabled(false);

webView.loadUrl(URL);
```

But when I execute it, I'm not able to load the url. I am getting web page not available.

Could anyone help?

Comment: Does loading the URL work in the default android browser?

Comment: Have you given Internet Permission ?

Comment: @LeonLucardie   working in device browser

Comment: @Lucifer yes given in AndriodManifest

Comment: Also make sure the url is starting with "http://" or "https://"

Answer (score 128, accepted):

Did you added the internet permission in your manifest file ? if not add the following line.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

hope this will help you.

**EDIT**

Use the below lines.

```
    public class WebViewDemo extends Activity {


        private WebView webView;


        Activity activity ;
        private ProgressDialog progDailog; 

        @SuppressLint("NewApi")
        @Override
        public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.main);

            activity = this;

            progDailog = ProgressDialog.show(activity, "Loading","Please wait...", true);
            progDailog.setCancelable(false);



           webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview_compontent);



           webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);     
           webView.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
           webView.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);        
            webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

                @Override
                public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                    progDailog.show();
                    view.loadUrl(url);

                    return true;                
                }
                @Override
                public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {
                    progDailog.dismiss();
                }
            });

            webView.loadUrl("http://www.teluguoneradio.com/rssHostDescr.php?hostId=147");

           }
    }
```

Comment: You saved my life. Thank you. Nice and clean code. i also learnt how easy it is to make a simple progress bar.

Comment: it's better to add Handler.post(hideDialog, 300) to not have blinking dialog

Comment: You are a god among men.

Comment: @deprecated Use {@link #shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebResourceRequest) shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView, WebResourceRequest)} instead.

Comment: In shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method, do not call WebView#loadUrl(String) with the request's URL and then return true. This unnecessarily cancels the current load and starts a new load with the same URL. The correct way to continue loading a given URL is to simply return false, without calling WebView#loadUrl(String). And this method may be called for subframes and with non-HTTP(S) schemes; calling WebView#loadUrl(String) with such a URL will fail.

Comment: @yoline  shouldOverrideUrlLoading() method is deprecated now, what is the alternative??

Answer (score 23):

maybe SSL

```
    @Override
    public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError error) {
        // ignore ssl error
        if (handler != null){
            handler.proceed();
        } else {
            super.onReceivedSslError(view, null, error);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 19):

Add Permission  Internet permission in manifest.

as `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

This code it working

```
  public class WebActivity extends Activity {
  WebView wv;

 String url="http://www.teluguoneradio.com/rssHostDescr.php?hostId=147";

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_web);
    wv=(WebView)findViewById(R.id.webUrl_WEB);



WebSettings webSettings = wv.getSettings();
    wv.getSettings().setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
    wv.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(true);
    wv.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    wv.getSettings().setPluginState(PluginState.ON);


    wv.setWebViewClient(new myWebClient());

    wv.loadUrl(url);
}




public class myWebClient extends WebViewClient {
    @Override
    public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;

    }
}
```

Comment: *sidenote:* you didn't use `webSettings` variable

Comment: Why is `setLoadWithOverviewMode` important?

Answer (score 18):

Note : Make sure internet permission is given.

In android 9.0,

Webview or Imageloader can not load url or image because  android 9 have network security issue which need to be enable by manifest file for all sub domain. so either you can add security config file.

1. Add @xml/network_security_config into your resources:

```html
<network-security-config>
    <domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">www.google.com</domain>
    </domain-config>
</network-security-config>
```

2. Add this security config to your Manifest like this:

```html
<application
   
    android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"
    ...>
</application>
```

if you want to allow all sub domain

```html
<application
   android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
    ...>
</application>
```

Note: To solve the problem, don't use both of point 2 (`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` and `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`) choose one of them

Comment: Note: To solve the problem, don't use both of point 2 (`android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config"` and `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"`) choose one of them. I couldn't open a url on android over 25 because I had both inserted in android manifest. :)

Comment: generaly remove android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" because what url you will open you dont know in live apk so if you are sure for domain then mention in  network_security_config as sub domain otherwise remove  android:networkSecurityConfig

Comment: i am facing the issue like below:
i have 2URLs the 1st url is not laod in Webview but when i click on 2nd url then try to load firs url at that time its; working fine.
-But every time i need to clikc on 2nd then 1st  please share me what the issue?

Comment: Add sub domain in your network security config file

Comment: @Yogendra i added sub domain name in that file 
still facaing the same issue at this time no webbview is loadded

Comment: @Yogendra actually issue with my desing side now  it's working perfect thanks!!

Comment: @Arbaz.in Cool. Hope it will help u. http://blogs.datanapps.com/

Answer (score 16):

For some web pages the key is to enable **DOM storage**:

```
webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Webview was not not loading URL with subdomain like food.misiki.in This trick solved that problem. Thank you so much

Comment: In my case the response from the webView was not sent to the target Url, what was very strange. This parameter solved the issue, somehow.... Don’t understand why. Thanks!

Comment: Solved my probelm. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

First, check if you have internet permission in Manifest file.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

You can then add following code in onCreate() or initialize() method-

```
final WebView webview = (WebView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.webview);
        webview.setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient());
        webview.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(false);
        webview.getSettings().setSupportZoom(false);
        webview.getSettings().setJavaScriptCanOpenWindowsAutomatically(true);
        webview.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
        webview.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
        webview.loadUrl(URL);
```

And write a class to handle callbacks of webview -

```
public class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
                           //your handling...
                return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }
    }
```

in same class, you can also use other important callbacks such as -

```
- onPageStarted()
- onPageFinished()
- onReceivedSslError()
```

Also, you can add "SwipeRefreshLayout" to enable swipe refresh and refresh the webview.

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
        android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webview"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

And refresh the webview when user swipes screen:

```
SwipeRefreshLayout mSwipeRefreshLayout = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipeRefreshLayout);
            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
                @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            mSwipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
                            webview.reload();
                        }
                    }, 3000);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the following things on your webview

```
webview.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
```

then implement the required methods for WebChromeClient class.

Comment: What are the required methods?

Comment: No methods are required in `WebChromeClient()`

Comment: In case someone also is facing the same problem, in order for the webview to load the web content, it's necessary to call its method `setWebViewClient` with a `WebViewClient` instance. There is no need to override any methods.

Answer (score 2):

Just as an alternative solution:

For me `webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString("Android WebView")` did the trick.

I already had implemented INTERNET permission and `WebViewClient` as well as `WebChromeClient`

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to go to your XML layout containing your webview. Change your android:layout_width and android:layout_height from "wrap_content" to "match_parent".

```
  <WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/webView"/>
```

Comment: Thanks you saved a lot time, This trick worked. Thanks again.!!

Answer (score 2):

In my Case, Adding the below functions to WebViewClient fixed the error.
the functions are:`onReceivedSslError` and Depricated and new api versions of `shouldOverrideUrlLoading`

```
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            view.loadUrl(url);
            Log.i(TAG, "loading: deprecation");
            return  true;
            //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, url);
        }

        @Override
        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest request) {
            view.loadUrl(request.getUrl().toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "loading: build.VERSION_CODES.N");
            return true;
            //return super.shouldOverrideUrlLoading(view, request);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageStarted(
                WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon) {
            Log.i(TAG, "page started:"+url);
            super.onPageStarted(view, url, favicon);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, final String url) {

            Log.i(TAG, "page finished:"+url);

        }

        @Override
        public void onReceivedSslError(WebView view, SslErrorHandler handler, SslError er) {
            handler.proceed();
        }

    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this it should help.

```
 var currentUrl = "google.com" 
 var partOfUrl = currentUrl.substring(0, currentUrl.length-2)

 webView.setWebViewClient(object: WebViewClient() {

 override fun onLoadResource(WebView view, String url) {
 //call loadUrl() method  here 
 // also check if url contains partOfUrl, if not load it differently.
 if(url.contains(partOfUrl, true)) {
     //it should work if you reach inside this if scope.
 } else if(!(currentUrl.startWith("w", true))) {
     webView.loadurl("www.$currentUrl")

 } else if(!(currentUrl.startWith("h", true))) {
     webView.loadurl("https://$currentUrl")

 } else { 
   //...
 }
 }

 override fun onReceivedSslError(view: WebView?, handler: SslErrorHandler?, error: SslError?) {
  // you can call again loadUrl from here too if there is any error.
}
 // You should also override other override method for error such as
 // onReceiveError to see how all these methods are called one after another and how
// they behave while debugging with break point. 
}
```