# Some of the option of website are not working in the web view

Tags: java, android, webview, web

I am opening a website in a webview. Website have a menu and cart option. Site is perfectly opening in the app but those option are not working.Please help me(Sorry for poor english)

Comment: Do you have control over the website? Have you opened it in a mobile browser and seen it work? What website?

Comment: yes it is working in mobile browser. It  is an e commerce website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These kind of issues arise sometimes due to JavaScript and clients used in website. These things are not automatically enabled in Webview. You have to enable those manually.

Check this link, use this code given in the answer:

[Android WebView not loading URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207094/android-webview-not-loading-url)

Hope it'll work for you!

Comment: Yes javascript was not enabled. Thank you