# Android Web Viewer to load external URL on start

Tags: android, web, viewer

Can anyone help me with the line that loads an URL directly in my web viewer? I have the viewer with no address bar and I want to display an external html from an URL. I would be very grateful!

Comment: You may want to share code of the efforts you've made already and the challenges you're having.

Comment: Can you please put some code you have already written. so it will be easier to solve your problem.

Comment: Don't forget to use `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>` This code is already on other posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207094/android-webview-not-loading-url or you can use something like abapks.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
WebView wv = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.website);
WebViewClient client = new WebViewClient();
wv.setWebViewClient(client);
wv.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
wv.loadUrl(url);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: Nonsense @jaySf. This was already good enough. Even overdone as only the loadUrl line would have provided all.