# WebView wont refresh in android 9 API 28

Tags: java, android, webview, android-webview, android-9.0-pie

I'm using a `WebView` that shows a map and a `Seekbar` to change the radius of a circle on the map.

When I test it on any device/emulator that is under API 28 it all works good.

Works good = when I move the seekbar, the radius changes.

For example

1) for Radius 10km

[image]

2) For radius 3km

[image]

However, on the device that runs API 28, no matter what the `seekbar` shows, it stuck on the initial load.

[image]

I read that I might add something to my manifest as it is suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207094/android-webview-not-loading-url/16207180) but it won't work.

Any idea?

Im using:

```
WebView MapView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wb_map);
WebSettings webSettings = MapView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
MapView.loadData(Map_HTML, "text/html", null);
```

To display it in my WebView.

Thank you