# google.com is working in my webview app but when i run the app my website link is not appearing

Tags: java, android, android-studio, webview, android-webview

when i replace webView.loadUrl("https://softcommerceltd.com/"); to webView.loadUrl("https://google.com/"); then the app works fine , i can brows google and do everything. but when i put my website url then when i run the app the app shows blank activity. my internet is fine. how i can solve that issue? is that fault of my website? that website working fine in my browser.

Mainactivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private WebView webView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        CustomWebViewClient client = new CustomWebViewClient(this);

        webView = findViewById(R.id.webView);
        webView.setWebViewClient(client);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("https://softcommerceltd.com/");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event){
        if(keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK && this.webView.canGoBack()){
            this.webView.goBack();
            return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}

class CustomWebViewClient extends WebViewClient{
    private Activity activity;
    public CustomWebViewClient(Activity activity){
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, String url){
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webView, WebResourceRequest request){
        return false;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.tochy.webapp">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Tochy">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below code statement

```
    webView?.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Also add **www.** in the beginning of URL

```
webView.loadUrl("https://www.softcommerceltd.com/")
```

for reference:
[Android WebView not loading URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16207094/android-webview-not-loading-url)